# Getting invalid email address format when I enter phone number

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am doing phone authentication on Flutter with Amplify Studio. I am getting this error when I register with phone number.

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: InvalidParameterException(message: One or more parameters are incorrect., recoverySuggestion: Enter correct parameters., underlyingException: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid email address format. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: d04e58b4-fe2d-4d02-987a-f640188903d3))
```

This is how I sign up

```
   Future<void> signUpWithPhoneVerification(
  ) async {
    await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
      username: _email.text,
      password: _password.text,
      options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
        userAttributes: <CognitoUserAttributeKey, String>{
          // ... if required
          CognitoUserAttributeKey.email: _email.text,
          CognitoUserAttributeKey.phoneNumber: _email.text,
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in your code. Take a look:

```dart
   Future<void> signUpWithPhoneVerification(
  ) async {
    await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
      username: _email.text,
      password: _password.text,
      options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
        userAttributes: <CognitoUserAttributeKey, String>{
          // ... if required
          CognitoUserAttributeKey.email: _email.text,
          CognitoUserAttributeKey.phoneNumber: _email.text, // here :)
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i am using the same textfield to enter my email and phone number... does that work too?

Comment: It seems the app wants a proper e-mail address. Try to debug the text if it's an e-mail address or not. :)